# How to update Wordpress website running on the Managed Instance Group on GCP

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, managed, stateless

I'm working Wordpress site running on the MIG, so, this means that it is stateless, and I can't modify the template.

My questions are:

- How can I update Wordpress version without destroy the website?
- How can I install some plugin?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation [Updating instances in a MIG](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/updating-migs)?

Comment: Yes but i thought it was only for a statefull MIG, i have a stateless one.

Comment: Please have a look on [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/updating-migs#choosing_between_automated_and_selective_updates) section. For more details, please have a look [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/rolling-out-updates-to-managed-instance-groups).

Comment: this solution leads me to modify the template, I would like to make these changes without modifying the template, as WP is connected to a db that keeps the changes despite being in an instance group.

Comment: Do you have MySQL database on your MIG instances? Unfortunately, there's no other way to update MIG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have a [Managed Instance Group (MIG)](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/working-with-managed-instances) that is running on Google Cloud Platform and you want to update your MIG to get updated Wordpress and add some plugin.

Please have a look at the documentation [Updating instances in a MIG](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/updating-migs): > You might want to update a MIG's [instance template](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates) for the following reasons:

> - To update your application or the operating system on each instance.

and

> Apply a new version of an instance template by using one of the
> following methods:
>
> - **Automated rolling update**. The MIG automatically rolls out a new version of an instance template to all or to a random subset of
>   managed instances in the MIG. The scope of the update and the level of
>   disruption depends on the update policy that you configure.

**To update your MIG** follow the steps below:

1. You should start from creating an updated image. To manage your images you should follow the documentation [Creating, deleting, and deprecating custom images](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-delete-deprecate-private-images).
2. After that, you can create a new instance template by following the documentation [Creating instance templates](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates/create-instance-templates). Keep in mind, that you're not able to [update instance templates](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates#how_to_update_instance_templates).
3. To apply changes to your MIG follow the instructions at the documentation [Automatically rolling out updates to instances in a MIG](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/rolling-out-updates-to-managed-instance-groups).

If something went wrong, you can [rollback an update](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/rolling-out-updates-to-managed-instance-groups#rolling_back_an_update).

Comment: Thank you Serhii Rohoza for your help! in the end I will proceed like this: 1) I will extrapolate an instance from the MIG 2) On this instance i will update Wordpress version and install all plugin i need 3)I will create a new template with images of these disks 4) I hope that nothing will destroy the DB that is shared between this test machine and the MIG

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. Please upvote/accept my answer if it was helpful for you.